# create a dictionary in python with a key and a list of values in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the dictionary

```
list = ["1", "2", "3"]
```

and a single key. now i want to form a dictionary like:

```
dic = {"key": "1", "key": "2", "key": "3"}
```

Does anyone know how to do it?

---

I have tried:

```
list = ["1", "2", "3"]

dic = {}

for value in list:
    dic['key'] = value
    
print(dic)
```

But it returns:

```
{'key': '3'}
```

thanks,
Marius.

Comment: You can't have duplicate keys in a dictionary.

Comment: Dictionaries cannot have more than one value for the same key.

Comment: As others have explained, it is not possible. But why do you want this? What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: in this case is there a possibility to make a list look like
```
list = ["key": "1", "key": "2", "key": "3"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible, Python does not allow duplicate keys inside a dictionary.
Keys act as unique identifiers thus Duplicate keys might lead to ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary, [by definition](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), can't have the same key twice.

Consider storing the values under the same key, using other kind of container, such as list, set or tuple:

```
{"key": ["1", "2", "3"]}
```